# wget ERROR: cannot verify localhost's certificate, ..Self-signed certificate encountered

Tags: linux, certificate, nginx, wget, https

**How Can I implement a secure https connection on ngnix**

I want to implement https on my localhost.I am running http server nginx on ubuntu 20.04

What I did was i issued the command

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt -config /tmp/openssl
```

Then I configured nginx to use ssl as

```
   listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key;
```

And Refreshed and reloaded nginix ...ok fine

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n localhost.crt -i /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt
```

. .Every thing went fine

The tutorial i followed was  from [here](https://develike.com/en/articles/adding-a-trusted-self-signed-ssl-certificate-to-nginx-on-debian-ubuntu)

But when i tried to connect to https://localhost

I got as

[image]

Then I clicked Advance and proceeded ..Then I got a MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT Error in Firefox

[image]

But when opening in chrome the error is

[image]

when i tried on wget

[image]

When I tried on postman

[image]

Please help me on how to get a secure self signed trusted https connection on localost

Comment: *How can I implement a secure HTTPS connection on Ngnix?* - Arguably, you appear to have already done this (i.e. set up Nginx to correctly serve your self-signed certificate). The issue(s) you are encountering are simply generic security warnings generated by each application individually. This means, unfortunately, that there really isn't a single way to prevent these (though it is possible to add your own trusted Certificate Authority or similar, which might alleviate some of the problem).

Comment: The simplest ways to get around the problem of self-signed certificates is to add security exceptions to your browser(s) (if possible), often under the `Advanced` menu or to use the other clear options to bypass verifying security certificates shown in your screenshots. An secure HTTPS connection should still be established, minus the warnings.

Comment: @Anaksunaman described it beautifully. Regarding `wget`, use option `--no-check-certificate`. In case you want to try `curl`, the equivalent option is `-k`. Finally, it is not too hard to create your own CA and add it to your browsers and the command line tools. Tutorials about this should be easy to find. A good exercise in my opinion.